# Why this sub is valid? Why i can pass each Type (String, Interface, Int) to a sub without compiler error as parameter

Tags: vb.net, parameters, interface, inversion-of-control

```
Public Class MainWindow

    Private Sub MainWindow_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Me.Loaded

        Me.x(1)
    End Sub

    Public Sub x(ByVal x As String)
        MessageBox.Show(x)
    End Sub

End Class
```

If I want a Interface in sub x as example `Public sub x(Byval IPerson)` it also accept every type without an error.

Comment: Turn on `Option Strict` and it wont compile. As is, VB converts `1` to `"1"` when passing the var.  Strictly speaking, there is nothing to do with interfaces there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VS2013 under Debug/Debugging/Projects and Solutions/VB Defaults is an option to turn Option Strict to on.

Comment: Yes. Absolutely. Strict should ALWAYS be on. Just like you should have the project set to 'Treat all warnings as errors'.